# How to disable window.onscroll function calling another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

I have two javascript functions.

First one is:

```
    function gallery(page)
    { 
      $.scrollTo( '#'+page, 1000, '#' );       
    }
```

The next one is like this:

```
      window.onscroll = function () 
      {
        makeCallv();    
      }
```

Here i want to disable window.onscroll function when gallery function is called. And scroll function should be active when function gallery is not called.

Can anyone help me as i am getting this problem for two days. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you are using the [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) jQuery plugin, with this plugin you can bind an event that executes when the scrolling animation has ended (`onAfter`).

You could unbind the window.onscroll event before calling the plugin, and re-bind it when the scrolling animation ends:

```
function gallery(page) { 
  window.scroll = null; // unbind the event before scrolling
  $.scrollTo( '#'+page, 1000, '#', {onAfter: function () {
      window.onscroll = makeCallv; // bind the event when the animation ends
    }
  });       
}

window.onscroll = makeCallv;
```

Comment: Was in the process of using this very solution. +1

Comment: Thanks CMS. It worked for FF, IE but not for Safari in Mac. 

Thanks again.